# gitlab and asana: commits from my team appear in Asana under single name

Tags: gitlab, asana

in Gitlab docs it says that it is possible to integrate with Asana and log commits as comments to Asana tasks. Which I did.

## I created a personal API key in asana:

[image]

## Entered it into Gitlab integration page:

[image]

## And my commits did show up in Asana:

[image]

## But there's a problem.

Now all my team's commits show up in Asana under my name. Which makes sense, because Asana API key was issued by me.

But this means that this integration is only suitable for Gitlab repositories managed by one person. This is weird.

Am I missing something here? How do I make team members post commits to Asana under their names?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour with a personal access token, as it authenticates as a user (currently you).  To avoid confusion you could create another Asana user (i.e. "GitLab Bot") and use a personal access token on that user.  I think that will avoid the confusion.